# Swift - Navigation Bar Not Appearing From Segue From Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, segue

Here is a picture of my storyboard:
[image: Here is a picture of my storyboard:]

I assume the problem is because the segue is coming from a custom table view cell. The button will send information based on the cell selected. When I press the button, I just perform the segue with identifier. Unfortunately, the navigation bar does not appear, and I can't imagine why its not appearing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the storyboard segue. It is push: [image: push]

EDIT2: Here is the code I am using to perform this segue:

```
 func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    segueIndex = sender.tag
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_show_job", sender: self)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue_show_job" {
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! PlaceBidTableViewController
        nextVC.job_info.job_info = self.job_arr_arr.job_info_arr_arr[segueIndex]
    }
}
```

ANSWER:

Maximo and XCoder, thank you for your help. Even though my segue was push, something must have been corrupted. I deleted the segue and re-created it and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: What is your segue type (push, modal, show) ??

Comment: @Xcoder123, It is push. I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure use Push in your view. [This is what suppose to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOdao.png)

[This make your navigation bar not show up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRWJv.png)

Comment: The segue is push. Any other advice for what could cause it?

Answer (score 0):

Maximo and XCoder, thank you for your help. Even though my segue was push, something must have been corrupted. I deleted the segue and re-created it and it worked! Thanks!